# mysqli doesn't insert into database

Tags: php, pdo

Good day,

I am using the code below:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO blogs (name, subject, message) VALUES (?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sss',$name, $subj, $msg);
```

It works without errors and page is responding fine.

Problem is, that I don't think it's actually inserting into my database?

Could someone please advise what could be causing this?

Thanks

Comment: You don't think it's actually inserting into your database or it is not actually inserting into the database? Are you asking question just on your guess?

Comment: asking if its inserting into database.

Comment: `bind_param` statement is not correct and it doesn't look like you are executing the query...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only prepare the statement and bind the parameters.. Aren't you have the execution part?

```
$stmt->execute();
```

This will guide to the solution

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Answer (score 0):

The execution is missing from your code:

```
  $stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not binding the parameters in the right way and you are not executing the query.

It should be:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO blogs (name, subject, message) VALUES (?,?,?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1,$name);
$stmt->bindParam(2,$subj);
$stmt->bindParam(3,$msg);
$stmt->execute();
```